# Rest API design: updating relationship

Tags: rest, api, api-design

I'm trying to find the best design for an API. I have `user` and `institution` objects. Each `user` can have only one `institution`, which is represented on the `users` table by an `institution_id` column.

How should I model an endpoint that would change which `institution` a `user` is signed up for?

Some of my ideas:

`PUT /user/institution` passing in the new institution_id in the body.

`PATCH /user` updating the `institution_id` column in `users`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `PATCH /user updating the institution_id column in users`

is better, because you are updating an attribute in the user model and you can consider it as any other attribute belong to the user like email, address .. etc, since institution_id is a column in user table.

Also using PUT will lead you to provide the whole model when you updating the user and this consuming your network traffic.

BTW, when using **PATCH** you only provide the attributes that's you want to update, and using **PUT** you provide the whole user model.

The return data from the **2 verbs** (PUT AND PATCH)should be the whole model not only the updated attributes.